# Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I've a simple microservice with Redis Database and RabbitMQ, i'm trying to enable Eureka Client and connect it to my Registry-service (Eureka Server)

I tried all of solutions in stackoverflow and nothing worked for me!

I've also enabled Eureka Client with annotions @EnableEurekaClient in the main class.

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2022-09-04 01:36:05.225  INFO 609955 --- [           main] c.e.r.s.SpringbootRedisProductService    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-09-04 01:36:05.787  INFO 609955 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-09-04 01:36:05.789  INFO 609955 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-04 01:36:05.810  INFO 609955 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2022-09-04 01:36:06.005  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=25453f64-f3dc-3e72-9597-60dfb523d761
2022-09-04 01:36:06.147  INFO 609955 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5440347] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-09-04 01:36:06.341  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-09-04 01:36:06.350  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-04 01:36:06.350  INFO 609955 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2022-09-04 01:36:06.458  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-04 01:36:06.458  INFO 609955 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1217 ms
2022-09-04 01:36:06.939  WARN 609955 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2022-09-04 01:36:06.940  INFO 609955 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2022-09-04 01:36:06.944  WARN 609955 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2022-09-04 01:36:06.944  INFO 609955 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2022-09-04 01:36:07.203  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-09-04 01:36:08.307  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2022-09-04 01:36:08.396  INFO 609955 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2022-09-04 01:36:08.412 ERROR 609955 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaRegistration           : error getting CloudEurekaClient

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:390) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:184) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:160) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:279) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:494) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4315ef37.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.redis.springbootredisdemo.SpringbootRedisProductService.main(SpringbootRedisProductService.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:411) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:302) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecacfc66.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecacfc66$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a6a5fbbf.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecacfc66.eurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder$MyDefaultApacheHttpClient4Config.createDefaultSslCM(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:290) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder$MyDefaultApacheHttpClient4Config.<init>(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:195) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:178) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.buildLegacy(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:230) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.build(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:204) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.create(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:161) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:485) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:398) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    ... 51 common frames omitted

2022-09-04 01:36:08.413  WARN 609955 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
2022-09-04 01:36:08.418  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is not active already
2022-09-04 01:36:08.419  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-09-04 01:36:08.532  INFO 609955 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-09-04 01:36:08.551  INFO 609955 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-04 01:36:08.554 ERROR 609955 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.redis.springbootredisdemo.SpringbootRedisProductService.main(SpringbootRedisProductService.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.redis</groupId>
    <artifactId>productservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProductService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.yml

```
spring:
    redis:
      host: localhost
      password:
      port: 6379
      lettuce:
        shutdown-timeout: 30000
        pool:
          # Connection pool maximum connections (negative for no limit) default 8
          max-active: 30
          # Maximum free connections in connection pool default 8
          max-idle: 8
          # Minimum free connections in connection pool default 0
          min-idle: 0

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

Application.properties

P.S: if i changed the **eureka.client.fetch-registry** and **eureka.client.register-with-eureka** in the application.properties to **false**, the microservice will run but the eureka client will not work.

```
spring.application.name=product-service
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You've got a version mismatch. Update to the latest version of spring boot 2.3.x and Greenwich. BTW those versions are no longer supported